# How to make SwiftUI Form translucent?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make the SwiftUI Form translucent. I've tried applying `.background(.thinMaterial)` modifier to the Form. However, this changes the look of the scroll view background. I'd like to apply translucency to the area that is white in the picture I attached.

Is there a way to do it? I am developing for iOS 16.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.pink, .yellow]),
                               startPoint: .topTrailing,
                               endPoint: .bottomLeading)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                Form {
                    VStack {
                        ...
                    }
                }.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `Form` is just a `List` under the hood. So by applying `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` you are clearing the `List` background.

By using `.background` on `Form` you are setting the background for the entire `List` again. To set the background only on the implicit `Section` you need another modifier. `.listRowBackground`.

But `listRowBackground` has this signature:

```
func listRowBackground<V>(_ view: V?) -> some View where V : View
```

So you can´t use `.thinMaterial`. But you can add a new background to the `VStack`.

A possible solution would be:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.pink, .yellow]),
                           startPoint: .topTrailing,
                           endPoint: .bottomLeading)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Form {
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $text)
                    Button("test"){
                        
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    Button("test"){
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
                // this will clear the background
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                // add some padding around the VStack
                    .padding()
                // apply a new background
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                // make the edges round again
                    .mask {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    }
                        
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Change the form's opacity to bleed through the background colour/image:

```
Form {
  /...
}
.opacity(0.5).  // 0 = fully translucent ... 1 = opaque
```